# Why are NgRx Action types formatted as an unenforced "[Source] Event" string?

Tags: ngrx

I'm reading NgRx's basic Architecture tutorial, and they explain about Actions:

> The interface has a single property, the type, represented as a string. The type property is for describing the action that will be dispatched in your application. The value of the type comes in the form of [Source] Event and is used to provide a context of what category of action it is, and where an action was dispatched from.

https://ngrx.io/guide/store/actions

I'm wondering about the rationale or benefit of not enforcing this kind of arbitrary string format? Why not have Actions enforce you defining both a `source` and `event` property that can be composed by the library into a `type` attribute? It seems like it leaves room for error, making it easy to ignore the recommended format. Is there any advantage to this?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a convention. Strings can be used as types, so it's "safe" from that perspective. At some point, the onus has to be on the developer to choose meaningful strings, right?

I tend to do this to keep things consistent for each suite of actions:

```js
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Config } from '../models/config.model';

const appAction = '[App]';

export const getConfig = createAction(
  `${appAction} Get Config`
);

export const setConfig = createAction(
  `${appAction} Set Config`,
  props<{ config: Config }>()
);
```

Here is a tangentially related [article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/lets-have-a-chat-about-actions-and-action-creators-within-ngrx-41277ecc739d) about actions and action creators. Interesting read, but doesn't truly answer your question.